# MediaPlayer.seekTo() not seeking to position on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on an app in which the video is paused at 3 different intervals. After the second pause, if a button is clicked, it should start back from the previous location.

Eg. if it is currently paused at 1:30, then on click of a button, it goes to the previous bookmark, i.e. 00:45.

I thought using MediaPlayer.seekTo() will help me achieve this. But, seekTo() doesn't seek the position at all. The currentPosition stays the same even after a call to seekTo();

Here's my code.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d("VID_PLAYER","Seek Complete. Current Position: " + mp.getCurrentPosition());
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

and somewhere below, I have this...

`mediaPlayer.seekTo(45000);`

What is the problem? Why isn't seekTo(); working?
Any help would be appreciated.

I am currently testing it on Android v4.0.3 (ICS)

Comment: Is your problem related with this : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9135

Comment: @ManishAndroid No. In my case, the log output is also wrong. It's not at all jumping to the new position. It starts from where it was paused.

Answer (score 7):

Try the code snippet given below to achieve more accuracy in seeking to specific positions of the media.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekPosition,MediaPlayer.SEEK_CLOSEST);
else 
    mediaPlayer.seekTo((int)seekPosition);
```

Keep in mind that -  as the accuracy increases, speed of seeking decreases. So while playing high resolution videos its advised not to use `MediaPlayer.SEEK_CLOSEST`more often.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons why Android is not able to do `seekTo` is because of strange encoding of the videos. For example in MP4 format so called "seek points" (i.e. search index) can be specified at the begining and at the end of the file. If they are specified at the begining of the file then `seekTo` will behave correctly. But if they are specified at the end of the file then seekTo will do nothing and video will start from the begining after `seekTo`.

This is confirmed bug-or-feature in Android 4.4.2.

**P.S.** On Youtube all videos are encoded with "seek points" at the begining of the file. So if you have this problem with `seekTo` in your app first of all check your app with some video files from Youtube. Perhaps you'll need to reencode your videos...

Comment: Any idea how to reencode the videos or audio files that the "seek points" will be at the beginning of the file and work properly with mediaPlayer?

Comment: Miro Video Converter:
http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Does your problem have something to do with this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4124

I recall encountering this about a year ago. I don't think I found a workaround at the time.

Comment: Yes @Dr.Dredel. It is similar to that. Although, that bug was in v1.6. I am using an ICS device to test my app. And acc to the comments there, the same problem exists on Jelly Bean also.

Answer (score 1):

Since API 26, Android added a

```
seekTo(long msec, int mode);
```

By specifying a `mode`, we are able to tell to our `MediaPlayer` how to seek:

- `SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC`: Has the same behavior as `seekTo(int msec)`. It looks for the nearest 'seek point' (i.e. sync frame) backwards.
- `SEEK_NEXT_SYNC`: Same as `PREVIOUS`, but looks forwards.
- `SEEK_CLOSEST_SYNC`: This looks for the nearest sync frame given a `msec` time.
- `SEEK_CLOSEST`: This seeks for the nearest frame given a `msec` time.

I faced a similar problem a couple days ago and by using `SEEK_CLOSEST` mode, this problem was solved.

For reference, check out these links: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(long,%20int)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types