# Why doesn't MediaPlayer.seekTo(t) go to the exact specified instant "t"?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to get the media player to play a specific range in a locally stored video. It doesn't seem to start at the specified time I tell it to.

Example: when I seek to 1000, it works. But when I seek to 1500, it goes to 2000 instead.

I also tried pausing seeking then starting on seek completion, it doesn't make any difference.

This is the code:

```
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.seekTo(time);
```

Is this normal? Or am I using the media player the wrong way?

Comment: [`seekTo(int msec)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29) should be in millisecond. Did you use millisecond?

Comment: Yes, I did. Let me clarify, if I seek to 1000, it works fine. But if I seek to 1500, it goes to 2000.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077026/mediaplayer-seekto-not-seeking-to-position-on-android

Comment: which version of android are you using?

Comment: @AndrewT. Well I can seek just fine but not to the position I want.

Comment: @gian1200 Android 2.3. I have tried on other devices and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: other devices, same version or other devices, other version?

Comment: @gian1200 Other devices, same version. On a Nexus S, it doesn't seek. On an Alcatel One Touch Evolve, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. Videos have keyframes ([i-frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)) that store more information than other frames. A non keyframe can be built only given the previous keyframe. Trying to display a non keyframe will show green spots and pixelated jittery screen.

Now, on some android devices there's no workaround implemented for this so you get this weird behavior. On a Nexus S for example `seekTo()` doesn't necessarily go to the specified frame. I tried other devices with the same android version and they seek just fine.

Comment: Key frame synchronization is a limitation of the Android MediaPlayer implementation. For instance, ExoPlayer does not have this limitation and is able to jump to arbitrary positions accurately albeit with a longer potential delay for frame composition.