# How can I keep track of the frame sequence when I use a media player and seek bar?

Tags: android, multithreading, seekbar

I would like to control a seek bar with both buttons and a user touch. I made all of them. 
When I play the video with a playback button, it works smoothly according to the frame sequence. The video starts from the frame where I pause.

The problem is that, however, when I change a progress on the seek bar by my finger touch, the thumb button moves a little bit frontwards and starts playing the video from the frontward frame. I want to start from the exact frame where I touch.

Can you help me out that the video starts from the exact frame where I touch?

```
  sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
  sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


          if(fromUser)
          {
              mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
              sb.setProgress(progress);
          }



          if(seekBar.getMax() == progress){

              isPlaying = false;
              mediaPlayer.pause();
              videoPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playback_tr);

          }

          progress_in = progress;
          Log.e("When progress change, frame number : ", progress_in+"");


      }


      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 


      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
      }
  });


  class MyThread extends Thread{

  @Override
  public void run(){

   while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

    sb.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    }
  }
 }




private void onVideoPlayback(View unusedView) {

    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {


        Log.e("-----------------When playbutton, frame number : ", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+"");
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress_in);
        Log.e("-----------------When playbutton, frame number : ", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+"");
        sb.setProgress(progress_in);
        Log.e("-----------------When playbutton, frame number : ", sb.getProgress()+"");



        mediaPlayer.start();

        new MyThread().start();


    }else{


        mediaPlayer.pause();

        videoPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playback_tr);

    }
 }
```

This below is the log results. The frame number should have started from 7363, but it was changed to 6144. What I want to do is that the frame number starts from 7363.

```
E/When progress change, frame number :: 6940

E/When progress change, frame number :: 7236

E/When progress change, frame number :: 7363

E/When progress change, frame number :: 7405

E/When progress change, frame number :: 7426

E/When progress change, frame number :: 7363

E/-----------------When playbutton, frame number :: 7363

E/-----------------When playbutton, frame number :: 7363

E/-----------------When playbutton, frame number :: 7363

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6144

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6167

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6170

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6171

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6172

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6173

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6174

E/When progress change, frame number :: 6175
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691394/6759241) for an explanation of the problem, and see the comment for a possible solution.

Comment: According to the link above, the problem came from the encoding matter. Is that the only reason for this problem?

Comment: What I would take away from that link is, "MediaPlayer can only start play on a sync (key) frame, but ExoPlayer can do the additional computations needed to start on an intra-frame." Since movies must have a finite key frame spacing in order to be practical, your best bet is probably to switch players.