# Android MediaPlayer seekTo not seeking to the right position

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I have a very simple app that seeks a particular position of an mp3 upon startup and starts the MediaPlayer from that position. I see, however, that while playing back the seek position is always shifted by about 2-3 seconds forward or backward. I have tried mp3s with 16, 32 and variable bitrates. Only wav files seem to be working fine but they are impractical due to their size for my purpose. Interestingly, if I calculate the seek manually (16*24000 in case of a 16 bit mp3 for instance) and pass it as offset to mp.setDataSource, it's working fine. I can't use this because I also need TimedText in my app, which doesn't work with offset. Would really appreciate help.

Here is the complete code:

```
package com.example.mediaplayertest;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener{
    static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("English text only.mp3");
            long length = afd.getLength();
            FileDescriptor fd = afd.getFileDescriptor();
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(fd, 0, length);

            afd.close();
            mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.prepare();

            mp.seekTo(24000);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        int pos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        //debug shows the pos value correctly as 24000 
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at my answer?

Comment: This issue is answered here : [MediaPlayer.seekTo() not seeking to position on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077026/mediaplayer-seekto-not-seeking-to-position-on-android/59798947#59798947)

Answer (score 0):

Your manual calculation is for offset in bytes, which is 16x24=384 KB. If mp3 is of 16 kbps, then you are roughly seeking to 192 seconds! Whereas, you are giving 24 seconds when calling seekTo(). What is the position you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I did not state my question properly. The bitrate of the mp3s I tried were 128 and 256 kbps and not 16 and 32 as I have mentioned by mistake in my question . By trial and error I found that for the 128 kbps mp3, to calculate the offset, I need to multiply by 16 and for 256 kbps by 32. So I set the offset to 24000X16 for a 128 kbps mp3 to seek to the 24th second pos. If I give the argument 24000 to seekTo, the expectation is it should move the starting point of the play to 24 sec regardless of the bitrate, which is not happening as seen from the code output.